# How to run commands when mac is idle and when it resumes

Tags: macos, power-management, hook

I want to run script when my mac is idle (for example after 5 minutes or screen saver start time is also ok) and when I resume it from idle state.

I know that I can write daemon using `NSDistributedNotificationCenter` and `com.apple.screenIsLocked` and `com.apple.screenIsUnlocked`, but I hope that there is already solution without creating new daemon.

I need this to for example turn on/off speed limit for Transmission (as it is sometimes hard to work when hashing/downloading on full speed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sleepwatcher -- See my answer to [Automatically run a program when mac wakes from sleep](https://superuser.com/questions/139416/automatically-run-a-program-when-mac-wakes-from-sleep/139420#139420)

Comment: I see how you can script 'sleep' events, but not when your machine goes to idle / inactive.

Comment: From Sleepwatcher's help text:  `-i or --idle
       execute idlecommand when no user interaction (keyboard, mouse)
       took place in the period given with the -t option`.

Comment: it doesn't recognize mouse move as "activity" on my big sur. + it only shoot once, no way to cycle it.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the batch command:

```
man batch
```

Comment: Man page says about queueing at specific time or when load average drops below special value, nothing about idle/resume