# Automatically run a program when Mac wakes from sleep

Tags: macos, sleep, autorun, wake-up

I want to set a program to automatically run when the Mac wakes from sleep. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't tried this yet, but:

> [SleepWatcher](http://sleepwatcher.darwinports.com/) monitors sleep, wakeup and idleness of a Mac. It can be used to execute a Unix command when the Mac or the display of the Mac goes to sleep mode or wakes up or after a given time without user interaction. It also can send the Mac to sleep mode or retrieve the time since last user activity.

More, at [MacOSXHints.com](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20060908113605812).