# Can you have a script run whenever you machine wakes up from sleep and/or when the screensaver unlocks?

Tags: macos, mac, launchd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automatically run a program when Mac wakes from sleep](https://superuser.com/questions/139416/automatically-run-a-program-when-mac-wakes-from-sleep)

I'm interested in both.

Answer (score 2):

Check out a program called SleepWatcher at [www.bernhard-baehr.de](http://www.bernhard-baehr.de/).

Comment: You need to set at least one other option (i.e. empty wakeup script or similar). The function `parseArgs` in the source code does not consider `--plug` and --`unplug` sufficient and complains `sleepwatcher: no useful options set`.

Comment: I was able to fix the source code, works like a charm. Add ` && ! args.plugcommand && ! args.unplugcommand` to line 506 inside the condition, `make` the source file and `mv` the finished program to its `/usr/local/sbin/` destination.

Comment: I just saw the OP does not need those functions. I'm keeping the comments up for when someone searches for the application or the error message.